# Wp includes access control

Tags: wp-query, css

Everyone peoples can easily acess to my wp-includes how can i hide or not visible files to users can anybody help me regarding it this is my wordpress website link see everybody can see this https://pifserver.ml/wp-includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you got an Apache server, use this full code in the .htaccess file:

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

As a bonus, I would also add this:

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Comment: bro can u resolve thats my .htaccess file please look into it and just say how should i put in this to resolve issue  https://ibb.co/QKC2YJg

Comment: Just put the code before or after what you already have.

Comment: i did this bro but its showing me 500 error after that

Comment: i can send u my server ftp details if u wanna check

Comment: Use this form: https://goo.gl/forms/p29R3T26HeFKxKu23

Comment: can u send me your discord or any other social app where i can contact u easily*

Comment: and bro see this i got this errors after that https://imgur.com/a/bdtQJEb

Comment: and should i enter my ftp details to there  goo.gl/forms/p29R3T26HeFKxKu23 ???

Comment: Yes please! It's the form I created for it

Comment: ok done bro i sent

Comment: Ok, hold on! I'll check

Comment: Ok am Waiting 

Comment: bro can u fix that now please ?

Comment: Take a look, it now works! (And accept the answer if you feel it helped! :) )